# PuppeteerSharp async javascript functions not awaited

Tags: javascript, async-await, puppeteer-sharp

When I load a web page that contains async functions using PuppeteerSharp, the code within the async functions never runs (or is not awaited, I'm not sure which)

C# code:

```
        await new BrowserFetcher().DownloadAsync(BrowserFetcher.DefaultChromiumRevision);

        var url = $"http://127.0.0.1:8080/?code={code}&id={id}";
        var file = "C:\\temp\\test3.jpg";

        var launchOptions = new LaunchOptions()
        {
            Headless = true
        };

        var navOptions = new NavigationOptions
        {
            WaitUntil = new [] { WaitUntilNavigation.Networkidle0 }
        };

        using (var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(launchOptions))
        using (var page = await browser.NewPageAsync())
        {
            await page.GoToAsync(url, navOptions);
            await page.WaitForSelectorAsync(".complete"); // This times out
            await page.ScreenshotAsync(file);
        }
```

Javascript code:

```
   onmount = () => {
        const params = new URLSearchParams(document.location.search);
        const code = params.get('code');

        // search is an async function (not included here for brevity)
        search(code).then(result => {
            this.el.classList.add('complete'); // not executed
            this.updateTitle(result.name);  
        });
    };
```

The async javascript works as expected in the browser, but not via Puppeteer / Chromium

Does anyone know why this might be?

Answer (score 0):

When I ran puppeteer as non headless and inspected the page, I was getting an ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID Error caused by an api call. All sorted now.